# Is it good for me to suggest my boss that he is working beyond his capacity

Tags: manager, quality

My boss is overwhelmed with too much of responsibilities.

Due to this, he is not able to control anything. He is checking only 1 or 2 high priority things. Actually, any of the things/projects, need  his attention and advises.

But, due to time lack, it is not happening.

Now, I feel, I would like to **suggest** him to reduce that burden so that he can bring the quality in the deliveries. By saying so, I also mean to him that give authorization on certain things to me as I am the next person to him in the hierarchy. But I actually don't mean that.

How to communicate this point to him, so that, he understands my point? I mean I can be constructive while advising this.

Comment: By what measurement have you determined that he is working beyond his capacity?

Comment: Why not just generally ask if he needs any help? Depending on how you two get along would drive any suggestion. Would you even mention how low quality is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Trying to define how much responsibilities your manager should take is clearly not your responsibility**. And delivering such message to your manager doesn't make you a self initiative employee. This should be his concerns, or his manager concerns and not yours.

Perhaps your can discuss with him about how his lack of attention due to his busyness with other projects or teams has caused problems within your team and ask him if he has any resolution for it.

Answer (score 4):

There could be several reasons he is not delegating:

1. He is overworked and has lost control
2. He does not trust his subordinates (you) enough
3. His personality makes him micro-manage

Telling him you feel he is overworked seems like a really bad idea, as you essentially will be telling your boss that he isn't doing his job. That could seriously backfire.

A less risky approach could be to offer to help him. Next time he seems overworked, offer to take a task you could do, off his hands. If you complete it successfully, continue to offer your help until he eventually starts delegating tasks to you.

It is probably a lot better that you demonstrate that you can ease his workload than have a conversation that will at the very least be awkward and potentially disastrous for you.